# Navigation one view controller to another getting

Tags: ios

I want navigate viewController to TargetViewController but I'm getting following error:

> 2016-05-11 15:47:27.182 Sum of Numbers[2882:209790] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bttn.'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001016f9f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000101173deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001016f9b89 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>   0x0000000100d40a6b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   288   4   UIKit                               0x0000000101c3104c
>   -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88     5   UIKit                               0x0000000101e5ea71 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109   6
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010163aa80 -[NSArray
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224    7   UIKit
>   0x0000000101e5d454 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864  8
>   UIKit                               0x0000000101c37c16
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381   9   UIKit                               0x0000000101c38542 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178   10  UIKit
>   0x0000000101c388a0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138   11 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000101c39013
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     12  UIKit                               0x00000001023db7e7 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController
>   _setPresentedViewController:] + 87    13  UIKit                               0x0000000101c08dde -[UIPresentationController
>   initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 133  14 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000101c4b9ba
>   -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4004     15  UIKit                               0x0000000101c4ec5c
>   -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 489   16  UIKit                               0x0000000101c4e76b
>   -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179  17  Sum of Numbers                      0x0000000100c756f8
>   -[ViewController Sum:] + 120  18  UIKit                               0x0000000101aa7e91 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>     19  UIKit                               0x0000000101c134d8
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     20  UIKit                               0x0000000101c137a4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>     21  UIKit                               0x0000000101c128d4
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601    22  UIKit                               0x0000000101b15ed1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835  23  UIKit 
>   0x0000000101b16c06 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865   24  UIKit
>   0x0000000101ac62fa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263  25  UIKit
>   0x0000000101aa0abf _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844  26 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101626011
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17  27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010161bf3c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556  28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010161b3f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867    29  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010161ae08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     30  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000104e95ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  31  UIKit
>   0x0000000101aa630d UIApplicationMain + 171    32  Sum of Numbers
>   0x0000000100c75aaf main + 111     33  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000103e1d92d start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

**My viewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Sum:(id)sender {
    TargetViewController *add = [[TargetViewController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"TargetViewController123" bundle:nil];

   // TargetViewController *membr = [[TargetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TargetViewController123"];

    [self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

I don't know where I get the error. Please help

Comment: Please edit your question and put both the error log and your code in code blocks so it's readable. As it is now the formatting is awful.

Comment: Check your outlet in storyboard by right click on yellow button of view controller.

Answer (score 5):

Your error is described here:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bttn.
```

This means that something is trying to call a property `bttn` on a class that doesn't have a property with this name. This often happens if you have connected an `IBOutlet` in your view controller, and then deleted it in the code but forgot to remove the outlet reference from your element in Interface Builder.

Comment: Great. You might consider accepting the answer if the solution was correct.